# Why IOS terminates application with call clientSystemApplicationTerminated

Tags: ios, multithreading, terminate, libc

My IOS application has many threads, usually 60.
and of of them sometimes (very rarely) receives next:

```
11 libsystem_c.dylib 0x0000000180fb5364 exit + 20
12 FrontBoardServices 0x0000000182e86fb4 -[FBSWorkspace clientSystemApplicationTerminated:] + 24
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000180f494bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000180f4947c _dispatch_client_callout + 12
15 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000180f554c0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 860
16 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000180f4cf80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 460
17 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000180f57390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 724
18 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000180f570b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
```

this thread is not 'main'-thread with UI.
and call 'clientSystemApplicationTerminated' invokes 'exit' from libC.

This would unexpectedly destroy (calls destructors) all static/global objects in application while application handles some data from network.

This absolutely unexpected way to terminate iOS application and I will ask help to understand this surprisingly logic to terminate an iOS-app.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In every case I've seen, this indicates an OS bug and is often related to an impending OS crash. Search for "Terminating since there is no system app" which is very likely in the logs (if you disassemble the simulator code for this method, that's what's logged immediately prior to calling `exit`). Some example discussions of this message:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20240

[App Crashing Entire Device On Segue for iOS 9 + Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180655/app-crashing-entire-device-on-segue-for-ios-9-xcode-7)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18164